# is it possible to play an interactive swf file inside an xna 4.0 windows project

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

Hi Ive been trying to find an answer to this question, but all i can find are people talking about converting the swf file to play on an x-box. I dont want to convert it i just want ot play it,  I'm trying to make a full flash menu that can be played when the xna game is paused. the menu does not have any control over any xna parameters.

Thanks..VilkaS

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at [Robin Debreuil's blog](http://blog.debreuil.com/?p=35).  He shows how to use Swf files in XNA.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ardman this is a whole lot better than what i asked, your the best

Comment: If this has helped, please click the hollow tick to the left hand side :o)